Laravel: Storage unable to write file
I'm working on a local project (just for fun). I'm on windows 10, wamp 3.3.5 64bits.
I'm using a controller to download some image html and then trying to save it using Storage::put($filename, $html), but I'm getting the following error:
exception: "League\\Flysystem\\UnableToWriteFile"
file: "C:\\www\\nudecollect\\vendor\\league\\flysystem\\src\\UnableToWriteFile.php"
line: 24
message: "Unable to write file at location: _xyz/9bfbda70-5aff-409f-8c1b-ba7569c86245/xyz-0000.jpg."


This is my app\filesystems.php
'wpcontent' => [
   'driver' => 'local',
   'root' => "E://www",
   'visibility' => 'public',
   'throw' => true,
],

If I wrap the put line of code and use file_put_contents(Storage::disk('wpcontent')->path($filename), $html), it doesn't throw any errors and creates the file:
try { Storage::disk('wpcontent')->put($filename, $html); }
catch(\Exception $e) { 
    if (!file_put_contents(Storage::disk('wpcontent')->path($filename), $html)) return ['s' => 0, 'error' => $e->getMessage(), 'line' => $e->getLine()]; 
}

The line Storage::put($filename, $html) will still create a new folder, but will no be writing the image file. I had to reinstall my wamp, but I remember the same line of code would work without any errors before. I can't remember if I had to add any lines to my apache folder or something similar.
Any tips?
BTW, if I try to write to other filesystem, then it will work, just can't make it write to E drive:
'external' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => storage_path('app/external'),
  'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
  'visibility' => 'public',
  'throw' => false,
],


Check the directories if exist, check the permissions for the storage

@NikolaKirincic Thanks Nicola, I confirm the directories exist. As far as I know, apache has write permissions:

If you are running Apache as a Service (the default setup for stand-alone & WAMP Apache installations), then that Apache Service is running under Windows' LocalSystem account.

This Windows account already has full read and write ('777') ...
So when you read instructions to chmod 777 this, chmod 755 that, etc, ... you can ignore those parts of the instructions. Apache already can read-from and writeout-to those directories.
